# Which ASP.NET Core base image for Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-linux-2

I want to build a Docker image of my ASP.NET Core application to deploy to an EC2 AMD64 instance using the Amazon Linux 2 AMI. Which Microsoft base image for the runtime should I use? Amazon Linux 2 is an RPM distribution I can see, but I don't know which tag that translates to on this page:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet